# How can I get the selected item from Jquery Datatable length menu dropdown?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to assign the selected Item to a var object in my Jquery, how can I achieve that ?

it should be something like

```
var selectedlength = $('#datasetGrid').selected item from dropdown length menu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`page.len()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()) API method to get table's page length:

```
var pageLen = $('#datasetGrid').DataTable().page.len();
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/L4un9bwL/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

var selectedlength = $('#datasetGrid :selected').text()